# Fetch API request only returns null

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm learning about the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and how I can use it. However, when I make a request to [this page](http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en) with valid json, the response returns `null`. I'm making this request on codepen.io so I know this deals with CORS.

```
const headers = new Headers();
const params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers : headers,
    mode : 'no-cors'
}

const request = new Request( 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en' );

fetch(request, params).then(function( response ){
    return response;
}).then( function( json ){
    console.dir(json.body);
});
```

The request in Dev Tools returns this:

```
Response
body : null
bodyUsed : false
headers :Headers
ok:false
redirected : false
status : 0
statusText : ""
type: "opaque"
url :""
```

From MDN:

`The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.`

So I'm wondering why there isn't a response body added to my request and what do I need to change/add to get the contents of the requested JSON?

Comment: because you are using the no-cors mode. That's what it does: allow to make arequest but not to get a response.

Comment: When I change `method` to `cors` I get this in the console.


`Fetch API cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Your main issue is/will be CORS - that API doesn't seem to allow CORS, so you can't "borrow" their resources in your page - you'll need a server side method to access that API on your pages behalf

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference to the the issue with using no-cors. It seems currently this will not work with the global window object. Via Postman it works fine.

[no-cors with fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)